# {% if loop.first %} and {{ loop.index0 }} not working with Matrix

Tags: matrix, entry-type

I have a problem with `{% if loop.first %}` and `{{ loop.index0 }}` with the following snippet:

```
{% for block in entry.locationSlideshow %}
  {% switch block.type %}
    {% case 'upload' %}
      {% for image in block.image %}
        <button {% if loop.first %}class="is-active" {% endif %}data-slide="{{ loop.index0 }}"><span class="show-for-sr">{{ image.title }}</span></button>
      {% endfor %}
  {% endswitch %} 
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that all buttons get the class *is-active* and *0* instead of 0, 1, 2, 3...

This is working fine outside of a Matrix field. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Regards
Ben

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment `loop.first` and `loop.index0` are relative to your `block.image` loop.

If you want them to be set based on your `entry.locationSlideshow` loop (the parent loop) you can use `{{ loop.parent.loop.index0 }}` and `{{ loop.parent.loop.first }}`

For more information see the [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#accessing-the-parent-context-in-nested-loops).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot for this precise explanation!